# onClick function of child of React Indiana Drag Scroll contianer not firing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onclick

I'm trying to get the ref to a child within a `<ScrollContainer>` from React-Indiana-Drag-Scroll, but the putting an onClick in the child div results in nothing firing.

My goal is to scroll the clicked element into view and if I'm approaching this incorrectly, please let me know.

```
const divRef = useRef(null)
const divRef2 = useRef(null)

// This function does not fire upon clicking the div
const childOnClick = (ref) => {
    if (ref.current) {
        console.log(ref.current)
        ref.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest", inline: "center"})
    }
}

return (
    <ScrollContainer>
        <div ref={divRef} onClick={() => {childOnClick(divRef)}}>
            <h3>Div Text</h3>
        </div>
        <div ref={divRef2} onClick={() => {childOnClick(divRef2)}}>
            <h3>Div Text</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Div Text</h3>
        </div>
    </ScrollContainer>
)
```

This is the gist of my code. I've tried adding an onClick prop to `<ScrollContainer>` which gives a mouseup event with no reference to the clicked child within the ScrollContainer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting an answer, I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Anyway, at first glance, I have spotted an error in your jsx code when you are calling the childOnClick(), you have curly braces around which prevents it from executing the function. Try removing them like so:

```
<ScrollContainer>
    <div ref={divRef} onClick={() => childOnClick(divRef)}>
        <h3>Div Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div ref={divRef2} onClick={() => childOnClick(divRef2)}>
        <h3>Div Text</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Div Text</h3>
    </div>
</ScrollContainer>
```

Comment: Those curly braces do not prevent it from executing, it creates an inline function for onClick to run.